# Why is Key not assigned by default to widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Other GUI frameworks such as MFC(Windows) and Qt Quick distinguish basic GUI elements by HANDLE or ID. I know that HANDLE and ID correspond to the Key concept in Flutter. I guess this has to do with some optimization. I'd like to know more precisely why the key value is not assigned by default to Flutter's widgets.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'd like to know more precisely why the key is not default in Flutter."?

Comment: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/keys-in-flutter-104fc01db48f

Comment: @Alexander What I meant was asking why the key value is not assigned by default to Flutter's widgets.

Comment: @rosh-dev  I already read the article, but there was no explanation of why the key value is not assigned by default to Flutter's widgets.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify that. "Why is Flutter's key not default?" makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is **declarative framework**. check this [article](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/declarative) to get understand about **declarative** and **imperative** UI styling. In most cases **Keys** are not needed in the **declarative** style because flutter clear entire UI elements and build them again in each frame. But there are situations where you need **keys** to uniquely identify a widget or fix some issues in same type of widgets.

Check these articles.

[keys in forms](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation)

[Use of keys and handling some UI issues with keys](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/keys-in-flutter-104fc01db48f)

A thinking shift is need to move from **imperative** to **declarative**.